# What Username launch the service?

Tags: linux, debian, services

OS: Debian 10.10

I'm searching other command than `cat /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service` to show the user running the service.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can run the command:

```bsh
$ systemctl show <service> | grep ^User
User=someuser
```

If the unit has not defined a user you won't get any results, `rsyslog` is an example.